# Outlook Add-In save Attachment to Disk with Javascript

Tags: javascript, office365, outlook-addin

Is there an easy way with the Javascript Api to save the attachment to e-mails locally ? I am grateful to every tip. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically.  You'd have to first save the attachment to your web server via another mechanism such as a web service, then present the user with an http link to download the file.